# Getting buddypress user name in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, buddypress

From within my buddypress PHP templates I usually get the username of any given user by referencing the user ID like this:-

```
<?php echo bp_core_get_username( '{{userID}}' ) ?>
```

However I need to retrieve the username from within an external Javascript file.

The user ID is already passed in as var aData[11].  I have tried the following with no luck:-

```
 $('td:eq(3)', nRow).html( '<div class="table-row"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/members/' + <?php echo bp_core_get_username( '"' + aData[11] + '"' ) ?> + '/song/?songsID=' + aData[10] + '"><h4 class="nomargin">' + aData[0] + '</h4></a>' + aData[1] + '</div>' );
```

I am trying to return a URL... This cirrently gives me:

http://www.mysite.com/members//song/?songsID=6

Whe it should be:

http://www.mysite.com/members/**username**/song/?songsID=6

Any ideas?

Edit: Below is the server side code that I am using to ouput the JSON

```
<?php

    $aColumns = array( 'song_name', 'artist_band_name', 'author', 'song_artwork', 'song_file', 'genre', 'song_description', 'uploaded_time', 'emotion', 'tempo', 'songsID', 'user' );


    $sIndexColumn = "songsID";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "wp_dbt_songs";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "";
    $gaSql['password']   = "";
    $gaSql['db']         = "";
    $gaSql['server']     = "";



    $gaSql['link'] =  mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) or
        die( 'Could not open connection to server' );

    mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) or 
        die( 'Could not select database '. $gaSql['db'] );



    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
            mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
    }



    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }



    $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }



    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());

    /* Data set length after filtering */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
    ";
    $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

    /* Total data set length */
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
    $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
    $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html you're setting is being set on the client side, not on the server side, meaning that the php code will not be evaluated.

I guess what you can do is either put the already-evaluated username in a hidden tag and get that using jquery or expose it to the javascript on the page within script tags.

**EDIT**: So is the `userID` or the username in the json as well? If not, you could probably put it there. I'm still not so sure what the situation is. But if you're currently passing the `userID` in the json and actually want the username as `bp_core_get_username` would return it, why not just put the already retrieved (with `bp_core_get_username`) username into the json as well?

In other words, in your php code, figure out what the username is based on the userid with `bp_core_get_username` and then pass that into the json. That is, if I'm understanding the situation correctly.

Comment: Of course... I feel stupid now.  However, your first suggestion is a no go as this link is within a javascript loop. (I am returning Json data into a filter-able table).  Could you elaborate on your second suggestion a little as I'm not quite clear how I would go about it.  Thanks

Comment: Actually both of my suggestions assumed you had access to the `userID` on the server-side and could therefore pre-fetch the username from it. Then all you'd have to do is find a way to expose that username on the page so that the javascript could pick it up. You could do this by putting the username in a hidden tag and then have jquery get it from there to insert it into your link, or you can have your php embed it into a `source` tag so that it's accessible as a javascript variable. Both routes seem messy to me, but they're all I can offer with the information you've presented thus far.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me Jorge...  Perhaps if I explain in more detail you may be able to point me closer to a solution.  I have a server side script which is outputting the contents of an SQL table in JSON format.  This JSON data is being fed in to a table which is being rendered client side.  in the database the user is stored as an ID, but in order to render the URL in each row I need to return the full buddypress username.  I suppose manipulating the server side script to perform the user name get would do what I need?  Would it help if I posted my server side script?

Comment: I've update my question to include my server side code.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I think you are correct and that this would be the best route to take.  You are understanding correctly.  I have the userID in the JSON and would need to use bp_core_get_username in my server side code to return the actual username rather than just ID (I would actually need to return both as I need just the ID for something else) The trouble is i'm relatively new to working with JSON and don't think I am capable of modifying the code myself.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm glad to help, but I can't really be bothered to make sense of that mess of php. I can give you some general advice though. Figure out how `$output` is formatted and then you'll know where to append `username`. I think you'll have to do it for each 'row', or whatever it is `$output` contains a collection of. You'll have to have access to the `userID` as well of course, so you can pass that to the buddypress function. I hope it works out for you.

Comment: Many thanks... Totally understood. At least you've set me off in the right direction.  And apologies for the poor PHP practice, I am just learning. Cheers.

Comment: No worries, please don't take my comment on the code personally. It's understandable for people whom are learning :) That said, once you try a bit to get your solution implemented, should you encounter any other problems you could perhaps ask a new, more specific question which might get more responses. Once again, hope it works out for you. Have fun learning.